# Kendo radio button checked dot not in center

Tags: css, kendo-ui, radio-button

As shown in the following image:

[image]

The dot is not coming to the center of the circle when Kendo radio button is placed inside Kendo window or a fieldset.

---

Update:

After some testings I find that the Kendo radio button's circle becomes smaller when placed in Kendo window or some other elements, thus caused the issue. 
I have tried to use css to resize the kendo radio button using the selector:

```
.k-radio or input[type=radio] { width:15px; height:15px}
```

Still can't change the size of the button.

Comment: Please add the shortest code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran across this same issue. I ended up adding this to the kendo.custom.css.

```
.k-radio-label:before {
  border-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-sizing:unset; //This is part of the problem I had
  -webkit-box-sizing: unset;  //This is part of the problem I had
}
```

This solved my problem, I really hope it helps you out as well.

Comment: wow, I really hope that it can solve my issue. I am going to test it in a few days. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea, the issue now is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but for mine the following resolved it.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csaFI.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYDdR.png)

```
.k-radio-label {
    left: -2px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-left: 23px;
}
.k-radio-label::after, .k-radio-label::before {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.k-radio-label:before {
    border-width: 1px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steve's idea, the problem is now solved. The issue is caused because I added this css file for Kendo box sizing issue with Bootstrap:

```
.k-animation-container, .k-widget, .k-widget *, .k-animation-container *, .k-widget *:before, .k-animation-container *:after, .k-block .k-header, .k-list-container {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

[Here is the link to Kendo UI Box-sizing:](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap)

to fix the issue, I need to override the kendo-radio-label to:

```
.k-radio-label:before {
  box-sizing:content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:content-box; 
}
```